Bit confused by the provided Matrix Equation
Snippet Of question and part of the solution
So, it is given that $\sum_{j = 1}^m w_{i,j}x_{j} $ = $ Wx $
But, the output should be something like $\sum_{j = 1}^m w_{i,j}x_{j} $ = $ w_{i,1} x_{1} + w_{i,2}x_{2} + ... + w_{i,m}x_m $ and this is not equal to $ Wx $. I am a bit rusty with my Linear algebra, so I am probably overlooking something very basic. If I do $ Wx $, then according to me, the output should be what I think Wx should look like

$\sum_{j = 1}^m w_{i,j}x_{j}$ is the $i$-th component of the vector $Wx$.

So, basically ith column of W multiplied by x right?

It is the $i$-th row of $W$ multiplied by $x$.

You put the same thing in what you think Wx should look like and the snippet of the answer. So I don't understand what you think Wx should look like.

Anyway, $Wx= \left( \sum \limits_{j=1}^m w_{i,j}x_j \right){i \in \mathbb{N} \cap [1;n]}$. In other words, $\left( \sum \limits{j=1}^m w_{i,j}x_j \right)$ would be the i-th term of the $n \times 1$ matrix $Wx$

I apologise for the oversight, I have edited it to display the correct image now

Oh, I see. Ok, so it is incorrect to say $\sum_{j=1}^mw_{i,j}x_j = Wx  $ right? rather it would be $\sum_{j=1}^mw_{i,j}x_j = (Wx)_i  $

Yup, technically yes, but i think they implicitly meant that $Wx= \left( \sum \limits_{j=1}^m w_{i,j}x_j \right){i \in \mathbb{N} \cap [1;n]}$. You can see it as a finite sequence in i, of terms $\left( \sum \limits{j=1}^m w_{i,j}x_j \right)$

Yeah, it makes sense now. Thanks for clearing that up for me.
